# Index Array out of bounds exception?

Tags: java

Accordin to the debug screen the error is in:

1.Line 61: (Class Sprite)

```
private void load() {
    for (int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) {
            pixels[x + y * SIZE] = sheet.pixels[(x + this.x) + (y + this.y) * sheet.SIZE];      //Here is the error.
        }
    }
}
```

2.Line 43: (Class Sprite)

```
public Sprite(int size, int x, int y, SpriteSheet sheet) {
    SIZE = size;
    pixels = new int[SIZE * SIZE];
    this.x = x * size;
    this.y = y * size;
    this.sheet = sheet;
    load();                                     //Here is the error.
}
```

3. Line 16: (Class Sprite)

```
public static Sprite spawn_grass = new Sprite(16, 0, 3, SpriteSheet.spawn_level);   //Here is the error.
public static Sprite spawn_stone = new Sprite(16, 0, 2, SpriteSheet.spawn_level);
public static Sprite spawn_water = new Sprite(16, 1, 3, SpriteSheet.spawn_level);
public static Sprite spawn_wall = new Sprite(16, 1, 1, SpriteSheet.spawn_level);
public static Sprite spawn_wall2 = new Sprite(16, 1, 2, SpriteSheet.spawn_level);
public static Sprite spawn_floor = new Sprite(16, 0, 0, SpriteSheet.spawn_level);
```

4. Line 23: (Class Player)

   ```
   public Player(int x, int y, Keyboard input) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.input = input;
   sprite = Sprite.player_forward;          //Here is the error.
   ```

   }

5.Line 46: (Class Game)

```
public Game() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width * scale, height * scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);

    screen = new Screen(width, height);
    frame = new JFrame();
    key = new Keyboard();
    level = Level.spawn;
    player = new Player(16 * 6, 16 * 4, key);       //Here is the error.

    addKeyListener(key);
}
```

What can i do? Help!

Comment: In this first code segment have you tried `SIZE - 1` as the loop condition?

Comment: Have you checked that `(x + y * SIZE) < pixels.length`  ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't  work :/

Comment: Where's this class? `SpriteSheet`

Comment: Well it seems the problem has too be in `pixels[x + y * SIZE]` so, this could be one of two things. 1. You initialized the array to the wrong size. 2. Your loops are iterating two many times.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Where?

Comment: `load()` method, you are setting `pixels[x + y * SIZE]`. It seems that a likely candidate is that `x+y*SIZE` is not a valid index for `pixels` array.

Comment: @JGerulskis `public static SpriteSheet spawn_level = new SpriteSheet("/textures/sheets/spawn_level.png", 48);` that 48 is the size, which is the size of the original image, if a I change that to something bigger(128 and up) it will stop giving me the error but the image will be pixelated(because is not scaled). So what do i do?

Comment: From what I can tell your loop logic should work. The problem is else where

Comment: @JGerulskis can you help me privately? That way I can send you the code

Comment: On here is fine so people in the future can use it as a reference

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arrays use an Array List because since `load()` is only in the constructor (only called once as far as I can see) you can append the elements instead of finding the correct index for an array. As a result, if you append a list you can never get an out of bounds error.

Array List Code:

`ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); //init list`

`list.add(); //put same thing you would with array in ()`

If the error still persist then the problem is the `sheet.pixels[]` however I can not see that code so if that is the problem I can't help you until I see where that was initialized

Comment: Yep, still error but i dont think it is in the `sheet.pixels[]` since its function is to only get an int it doesnt return anything... right?

Comment: If it's returning an integer why do you have brackets after `sheet.pixel`?

Comment: `public final int SIZE;` ; 
`private int x, y;` ; 
`public int[] pixels;` ; 
`private SpriteSheet sheet;` ;   these are the variables

Comment: `(x + this.x) + (y + this.y) * sheet.SIZE` this is wrong